# Assets not getting parsed in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have laravel 7.3 installed

```
  <link href="{{asset('_admin/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="{{asset('_admin/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

assessing public folder from view

but getting 404 Not found.

Screenshot Attached
[image]

Comment: can you post the code where you are using asset helper

Comment: It looks like your `{{ asset() }}` calls are being output rather than executed, which probably means you named your view file `something.php` instead of the proper `something.blade.php`.

Comment: how are you returning the view from the controller ?

Comment: @ceejayoz: thanks my issue got resolved

Comment: @user3653474 Great; I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's Blade templating language (the `{{ asset() }}` calls are using this) only gets executed if the view's filename ends with `.blade.php`. If you name it `something.php`, they won't be executed.